# База данных на тему "Управление поликлиникой"

Tags: база-данных

Здравствуйте!
Я, разумеется, понимаю, что "борзею", но может быть кто-то сталкивался с такой темой либо хорошо ориентируется в данной предметной области.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, приблизительно какие сущности и связи лучше всего создать для проектирования базы данных по теме. Пусть обобщенно очень, но мне нужно от чего-то оттолкнуться.

Заранее всем спасибо огромное! ;)

Comment: вы для себя определите цели "Управления поликлинникой", чем вы будете управлять, какие данные хранить, какие отчеты необходимо будет создавать -тогда все встанет на свои места. И этому процессу лучше уделить много времени (всмысле не жалеть), а то на половине проекта окажется что-то неучли и возможно придется менять архитектуру.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на вскидку сущности:

1. Врач (специалист)
2. Время приема/кабинеты
3. Пациент
4. Справочники

Связывающие тбл: 1-2, 2-3

Comment: Можно немного расширить ответ @akalend

 5. Предоставляемые услуги
 6. Стоимость услуг
 7. Заявки на приём/лечение
 8. Отзывы/Вопросы/Жалобы/Предложения

Comment: можно еще вести историю болезней...
статистику по болезням, смертям и рождениям, это основная отчетность поликлиники, а также начисление бонусов к зарплате за платные услуги врачей, учет стат-талонов, расчет выполнения нормативов труда и расчет надбавок за переработку (принято 23 пациента из 18 положенных, отработать 40 часов на 10 000 приписного населения, к сожалению - ставки врачей снижаются, а население увеличивается )...
пусть сперва первое сделает, хотя с услугами - это правильно